# I am receiving "TypeError: middleware must be a function!"

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js and I dont know how to fix this error:

```
D:\Uni\Projects\Bulanovm\node_modules\koa\lib\application.js:121
    if (typeof fn !== 'function') throw new TypeError('middleware must be a function!');
                                  ^

TypeError: middleware must be a function!
    at Application.use (D:\Uni\Projects\Bulanovm\node_modules\koa\lib\application.js:121:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Uni\Projects\Bulanovm\index.js:45:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

I searched for solutions but I wasn't able to find anything that could help me. This is the code I am trying to run:

```
'use strict'

const Koa = require('koa')
const Router = require('koa-router')
const views = require('koa-views')
const staticDir = require('koa-static')
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser')
const koaBody = require('koa-body')({multipart: true, uploadDir: '.'})
const session = require('koa-session')
const sqlite = require('sqlite-async')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-promise')
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const mime = require('mime-types')

const accounts = require('./modules/accounts')

const getadminlogin = require('./routes/admin/get/login')
const getadminfrontpage = require('./routes/admin/get/frontpage')
const getadminregister = require('./routes/admin/get/register')
const getadminlogout = require('./routes/admin/get/logout')

const postadminlogin = require('./routes/admin/post/login')
const postadminregister = require('./routes/admin/post/register')
const postadminqoute = require('./routes/admin/post/quote')

const getuserlogin = require('./routes/user/get/login')
const getuserfrontpage = require('./routes/user/get/frontpage')
const getuserregister = require('./routes/user/get/register')
const getuserlogout = require ('./routes/user/get/logout')
const getuserproblem = require ('./routes/user/get/problem')

const postuserlogin = require ('./routes/user/post/login')
const postuserregister = require ('./routes/user/post/register')
const postuserproblem = require ('./routes/user/post/problem')

const app = new Koa()
const router = new Router()

app.keys = ['darkSecret']
app.use(staticDir('public'))
app.use(bodyParser())
app.use(session(app))
app.use(views(`${__dirname}/views`, { extension: 'handlebars' }, {map: { handlebars: 'handlebars' }}))

app.use(getadminlogin) //line 45 
app.use(getadminfrontpage)
app.use(getadminregister)
app.use(getadminlogout)
app.use(getuserfrontpage)
app.use(getuserlogin)
app.use(getuserregister)
app.use(getuserlogout)
app.use(getuserproblem)
app.use(postadminlogin)
app.use(postadminregister)
app.use(postadminqoute)
app.use(postuserlogin)
app.use(postuserregister)
app.use(postuserproblem)

const port = 8080
const saltRounds = 10
/**
@name Home 
@route
@authentication
*/
app.use(router.routes())
module.exports = app.listen(port, async() => {
    const db = await sqlite.open('./website.db')
    await db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tech (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, pass TEXT);')
    await db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, user TEXT, pass TEXT);')
    await db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS repairs (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                    applianceType TEXT, years INEGER, manufacturer TEXT, description TEXT,
                    addedBy TEXT, completed INTEGER, techquote INTEGER);`)
    await db.close()
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

(D:\Uni\Projects\Bulanovm\index.js:45:5) line 45 is app.use(getadminlogin)
Any help and an advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Error is at this line `(D:\Uni\Projects\Bulanovm\index.js:45:5)` **line 45** of this file, please specify which line is that in the above pasted code

Comment: The default export of the file `routes/admin/get/login` is not a function. Maybe it's an object containing a function?

Answer (score -1):

Please give your middleware code,Now I give a solution.Since there is no code, I don’t know if this is possible.
In your middleware

```
module.exports = () => {
   return getadminlogin // return your middleware code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

my example

```
// app.ts

const migrate = require('./handlers/migrate')
router.use('/migrate', migrate.routes())


// handlers/migrate.ts

module.exports = router
```